# How removing ANONYMOUS blocks from layout?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, local.xml

There is a block in `/customer/account/create` page named **ANONYMOUS_55**. It is created by `Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Taxvat`. I would like to remove this block from layout but both `remove` or `unsetChild` methods are not working. Any ideas why?

This is the code I used in `local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <remove name="ANONYMOUS_55" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

Comment: That block adding at `before html`?

Answer (score 1):

You can show/hide Tax/VAT field from system configuration:

> System > Config > Customers > 
>   Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > **Show Tax/VAT Number**

---

tltr:

I think it isn't possible via layout update.

Theoretically you could add an observer to `core_layout_block_create_after` and use somethink like this:

```
public function unsetTaxBlock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Taxvat) {
        $block->getLayout()->unsetBlock($block->getNameInLayout());
    }
}
```

**BUT**, in this would give you an error in registration form, because you would call `isEnabled()` on `null`.

```
        <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
```

You could change it to `<?php if ($_taxvat && $_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>` ...

Is there anything wrong using config settings?

Comment: I appreciate for your suggestion. I agree. The main goal based on GDPR regulations, no more VAT collecting in Frontend for humans. But for checkout process I have to show the input box for VAT number because in my country it is necessary being mentioned on Invoices for companies and humans. It will not be a required field, if someone is not providing it I can prove I requested it according to the legislation.

Comment: @ADDISON74 You can set it as required or optional from config. Making it optional should be OK for (german) GDPR.

Comment: GDPR is good but some people got crazy. We received complains why there is an input box for VAT (optional) when creating an account. So, I set "Show Tax/VAT Number" value to No. For checkout I had to set "Show VAT Number in Frontend" to Yes. In order to get no trouble when VAT could be required in the future, I set its value to UNSPECIFIED for every new account.